# Typescript Union Type for each Property of another Type

Tags: typescript

I have the following class:

```
export class User {
  id: string;
  updatedAt?: Date;
  createdAt: Date;
  email: string;
  emailVerified: boolean;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  dateOfBirth?: Date;
}
```

And I now want to create another type that picks a few properties and has FieldValue as a type Union on every property:

```
export type UpdateUser = {
  email?: string | FieldValue;
  emailVerified?: boolean | FieldValue;
  firstName?: string | FieldValue;
  lastName?: string | FieldValue;
  dateOfBirth?: Date | FieldValue;
};
```

Is there any way to do this other than to manually define the type unions on every property?

Best
Philipp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure there is a wayt to do it:

```js
type FieldValue = { age: number };

export type Initial = {
    email?: string;
    emailVerified?: boolean;
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    dateOfBirth?: Date;
};

// This is our helper
type Unionize<T, K> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] | K
}

type UpdateUser = Unionize<Initial, FieldValue>
```